# what are "index" in Three js JSON attributes

Tags: json, three.js, blender, 3d-modelling, 3d-model

I have exported 3D model into json using Blender.
It looks like:
[index is highlighted with yellow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0xLu.jpg)

My query is what this "index" represents? How it is populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index represents the index buffer of an indexed `BufferGeometry`. From the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.index):

> Allows for vertices to be re-used across multiple triangles; this is called using "indexed triangles" and works much the same as it does in Geometry: each triangle is associated with the indices of three vertices. This attribute therefore stores the index of each vertex for each triangular face. If this attribute is not set, the renderer assumes that each three contiguous positions represent a single triangle.

BTW: The Blender JSON exporter was removed with `R93`. Please export your models as `glTF` instead. It's the recommended 3D format of `three.js`. Read the following guide for more information about this topic:

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models

`three.js R100`